# Is it possible to remove bottomNavigation Bar while moving from one fragment to another fragment?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragments, bottomnavigationview

I want to remove bottom Navigation bar while moving from one fragment to another fragment. This is how I am trying to remove bottom Navigation bar.

```
class LoadFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_load, container, false)
        val bottomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)

        bottomView.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_home_navigation).visibility = View.GONE
        return view
    }
}
```

The bottom Navigation bar is present in Main Activity. I am trying to move from one fragment to another fragment but in that fragment there is no need of bottomNavigation bar. I don't know if it is possible or not. I am just trying new things.

Comment: Are you following MVVM pattern. Viewmodel?

Comment: Yes. I am using MVVM pattern.

Comment: Use shared viewmodel add a mutable flow  or livedata set the value in fragment listen in your activity.

Comment: It won't work.

val bottomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)

        bottomView.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_home_navigation).visibility = View.GONE

Comment: Sorry I am new in android. I searched for MVVM. Now, I know little bit about it. Actually, I am not using MVVM. I thought as there is view in fragment, it is MVVM. I was wrong. I saw its examples.

Comment: Try below ans it'll work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write a function in your Activity

```
    fun setBottomNavVisibility(visibility: Int){
      YOUR_BOTTOM_NAV_VIEW.visibility =visibility
    }
```

In your Fragment

```
    // SHOW BOTTOM NAVIGATION
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).setBottomNavVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
    // HIDE BOTTOM NAVIGATION
    (requireActivity() as MainActivity).setBottomNavVisibility(View.GONE)
```

Comment: remove these lines

val bottomView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main, container, false)

        bottomView.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_home_navigation).visibility = View.GONE