# How to hide botton navigation view from certain fragments?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

I am working on an application where I m using bottom navigation. I have four menu options on the bottom on one menu Post Ad I have a button("Start listing your property") through that I went inside another fragment but the problem is that the bottom navigation menu is showing there too now how can I stop showing this there??

i attached the photo
[image]
[image]

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

NavController navController;
BottomNavigationView bottomNavigationView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.fragmentContainerView);
    bottomNavigationView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_bottom_navigation_view);
    NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(bottomNavigationView, navController);

}

public void setBottomNavigationVisibility(int visibility) {

    MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(visibility);
}}
```

**Code of the activity where I don't want to use the bottom nav**

```
public class Details_Added_Fragment extends Fragment {


private PageViewModel viewModel;
FragmentDetailsAddedBinding binding;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    binding = FragmentDetailsAddedBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =  binding.getRoot();

    viewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(PageViewModel.class);

    ((MainActivity) requireActivity()).setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.GONE);

    binding.toolbar.setNavigationOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
           Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment2_to_postad);
        }
    });



    binding.next2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                enterName(binding.edittextName.getText().toString());
                enterEmail(binding.edittextName.getText().toString());
                enterDesc(binding.edittexDesc.getText().toString());

                Navigation.findNavController(view).navigate(R.id.action_secondFragment2_to_lastFragment);

        }
    });

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    binding = null;
}

public void enterName(String name)
{
    viewModel.setName(name);
}

public void enterEmail(String email)
{
    viewModel.setEmail(email);
}

public void enterDesc(String desc)
{
    viewModel.setDescription(desc);
}
```

}

XML of the above fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SecondFragment">

<androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:elevation="30dp"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_baseline_arrow_back_24"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add the Details First Screen"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittextName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter Your Name"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40sp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
    android:padding="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/toolbar" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edditextEmail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
    android:hint="Enter Your Email"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:padding="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edittextName" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edittexDesc"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="20sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="20sp"
    android:hint="Enter Your Description"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:padding="15dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edditextEmail" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/next2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="15dp"
    android:text="Next"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="20dp" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Comment: Create a method in your activity setNavVisiblity something. Call it from your fragment.

Comment: thank you brother for respons but as i am new to android can you elaborate it a little more for me?? please brother

Comment: Java or kotlin?

Comment: in java brother

Comment: Follow this ques: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72966060/is-it-possible-to-remove-bottomnavigation-bar-while-moving-from-one-fragment-to/72966333#72966333

Comment: brother the code you have provided is in kotlin..please provide it in java

Answer (score 0):

Create a method in your activity

```
public void setBottomNavigationVisibility(int visibility) {
    YOUR_BOTTOM_NAV_VIEW.setVisibility(visibility);
}
```

Call the method in your fragments. Whenever you want show hide  like below

```
 ((YourActivity) requireActivity()).setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.GONE);
 ((YourActivity) requireActivity()).setBottomNavigationVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: thanks brother but it is throwing null pointer exception on the method line     YOUR_BOTTOM_NAV_VIEW.setVisibility(visibility);

Comment: Add XML and Java sample here

Comment: Add the log as well

Comment: brother the problem is taking place when i m trying to add the bottoom nvigtion variable on the setBottomNavigationVisibility method on this line         bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(visibility);

Comment: here it is saying the id not find and throwing null pointer exception

Comment: What you're doing ?
 MainActivity activity = new MainActivity();
    bottomNavigationView.setVisibility(visibility);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247197/discussion-between-gobu-csg-and-vivek-m-fauzdar).

Comment: Is it correct id: activity_main_bottom_navigation_view

Comment: nothing brother it was placed by mistake(Main activity) i remove it still the same problem) and the id is correct